# Stemming corpus in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I am using the `library(tm)` package in R to stem words in R but I am still getting different words with the same root in the document term matrix (dtm).  For example, I am getting  "certif" and "certifi" as different words, "categor" and "categori" as different words, "cathet" and "catheter" as different words, "character" and "characteristi" as different words, and so on.  Isn't `stemDocument` supposed to take endings off and count them as one word?  How can I fix this? This is the code I used:

```
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$Long_Descriptor)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation) %>%
  tm_map(removeNumbers) %>%
  tm_map(content_transformer(tolower), lazy = TRUE) %>%
  tm_map(removeWords, stopwords("english"), lazy = TRUE) %>%
  tm_map(stemDocument, language = c("english"), lazy = TRUE) 

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
```

Comment: There is no "perfect" stemming algorithm out there. The default algorithm used by `stemDocument` is Porter’s stemming algorithm. If you [test this algorithm](http://9ol.es/porter_js_demo.html) with words like "category" and "categorization" you'll see they wind up with different stems. You can either create your own stemming algorithm, or maybe define a set of stems that you think are synonymous and replace them yourself. This is not an easy problem to solve.